# How to have multiple ids in the where clause in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a syntax problem with the following :

```
MATCH (u:User)-[c:aaa]->(n:bbb)-[r:ccc]->(n1:ddd)-[r1:eee]->(n2:fff) 
Where u.id = 1588 
Return u, n2 limit 25
```

My problem is the where clause... how can I add more than one id in the where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IN](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_lists) is your friend:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[c:aaa]->(n:bbb)-[r:ccc]->(n1:ddd)-[r1:eee]->(n2:fff) 
WHERE u.id IN [1588,1688,1788] 
RETURN u, n2 LIMIT 25
```